# Is it possible for Spinnaker to bake an image without a package?

Tags: spinnaker

For example I want to bake a grafana server, but rely on Salt (https://saltstack.io) to manage both install and its configuration. I'm not actually building grafana, so I don't have an upstream 'package' like a `.deb` or `.rpm` produced.

However, I still want to use Spinnaker and get all the benefits of immutable infrastructure: a change in Salt code results in a new AMI, and a new pipeline to deploy.

Is this a use-case of Spinnaker? It seems to mark the package as a required field, but in my testing it is not failing yet. Am I going to run into something downstream? Am I fighting against the tool and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the ui does treat 'package' as a required field, you can certainly employ bakes that do not require an os package. You will most likely still want to pass some placeholder package argument that can be used to dedupe bake requests. There are some details in this article about this: https://blog.spinnaker.io/spinnaker-rosco-deduping-logic-e03716e04a30

You'll also want to create your own custom packer template that provisions the require Salt bits and then reference that custom template under the "Show Advanced Options" section in your Bake stage configuration ui.

Thanks,
-Matt